# Serialization Collections with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have some problems serializing generic collections with protobuf-net. The classes are defined as follows:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DOPerson
{
    public DOPerson() { }


    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DOPersonCollection : DOCollection<DOPerson>
{
    public DOPersonCollection() : base() { }
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class DOCollection<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public DOCollection() { }

    [ProtoMember(100)]
    public Guid CollectionGuid { get; set; } 
}
```

To test the serialization I have the following main function:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DOPerson personOne   = new DOPerson() { FirstName = "One", Surname = "Person" };
        DOPerson personTwo   = new DOPerson() { FirstName = "Two", Surname = "Person" };
        DOPerson personThree = new DOPerson() { FirstName = "Three", Surname = "Person" };

        DOPersonCollection personCollection1 = new DOPersonCollection();
        personCollection1.CollectionGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        personCollection1.Add(personOne);
        personCollection1.Add(personTwo);
        personCollection1.Add(personThree);

        // Searialize the Collection
        MemoryStream memBuffer = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(memBuffer, personCollection1);

        // Deserialize the Collction
        memBuffer.Position = 0;
        DOPersonCollection personCollection2 = Serializer.Deserialize<DOPersonCollection>(memBuffer);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Person Collection 1 GUID : {0}", personCollection1.CollectionGuid.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Person Collection 1 Count: {0}", personCollection1.Count));
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Person Collection 2 GUID : {0}", personCollection2.CollectionGuid.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Person Collection 2 Count: {0}", personCollection2.Count));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The result produced are as follows:

Person Collection 1 GUID : db4ff817-db79-4588-98af-d730800add2e
Person Collection 1 Count: 3

Person Collection 2 GUID : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Person Collection 2 Count: 0

The first serialization produces an empty buffer and it therefore creates and empty collection object second time around. Is there any mechanism to handle this kind of scenario properly to produce the required serialization results?

Answer (score 0):

At current, an object is **either** a collection **or** a data object. There is not any room for overlap in the raw protobuf specification. My advice would be: if you need to store other data, then you should *encapsulate* a collection rather than *injerit* one, I.e. instead of:

- YourType : SomeCollection

  - SomeDataMember

To have:

- YourType

  - Items (a list of some kind)
  - SomeDataMember

Which will work fine.

There *is* a failing to suppress list handling (and use member handling instead), but: my advice remains encapsulate rather than inherit. Then it should work fine.